# Running tasks in remote server via SSH - life cycle?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, memory-usage, tail

Two related questions:

1. If I ssh into a remote server and start a long running task in the foreground (`:~$ ./my-task > out.log`), will the process continue to run when my connection to the server ends?
2. The same long running task from question #1 takes about 5 minutes to run. If I open another terminal window and play around with the file where the output is being sent (`tail -f out.log | grep 'Loop count'`) can that impact the amount of time it'll take `my-task` to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you kill your connection to your server, the task will end. I use `Tmux` for this kind of stuff.

You can install it in the normal manner.

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

The idea is you `ssh` into your server, then from with your shell start `tmux` and attached to a tmux virtual console. Start your stuff going from within the `tmux` virtual console, detach from it then kill your connection to the server.

The `tmux` virtual console will remain running, and so will all your stuff within that conole. You can connect to your server and attach to / detach from `tmux` consoles at will.

Tmux has a half decent man page, but here are a few keys to get you going.

`tmux ls` list running tmux sessions.

`tmux attach -t 0` attach to 0.

`ctrl-B c` create a terminal.

`crtl-B d` detach a termianl.

`ctrl-B "` split terminal vertically.

`ctrl-B %` split terminal horizontally.

`arrows` navigate panes.

`0-9` selects windows.

`s` switches sessions.

Hope that helps as a starter.