# What could cause my SSH connection to die (Connection reset by [ip]) + kills my background process?

Tags: ssh, background-process

I need some advice. I have a Digital Ocean droplet, which I SSH into it and start my java application with the following command:

`java ...  &> stdout.txt &`

(this should, from what I understand, save the stdout to `stdout.txt` but also launch the application as a background process in ubuntu)

and then I go `less stdout.txt` and `shift+F` to follow.

But for some reason, sometimes my SSH connection dies (I get logged out back to my Windows terminal) and I get a `Connection reset by [server ip] port 22`.

But strangest thing is that my Java app also dies.. even though it was launched as a background application with `&`.

I can understand if I get kicked out from my SSH connection, but I obviously want to keep my Java application running all the time.

What could kill both my SSH connection but also kill my background Java application?

Comment: see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/828668/running-tasks-in-remote-server-via-ssh-life-cycle/828675#828675)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running tasks in remote server via SSH - life cycle?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/828668/running-tasks-in-remote-server-via-ssh-life-cycle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That your background process dies when SSH is disconnect is normal and expected. To prevent a background process to die when the SSH session is disconnected you may want to try [`nohup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/nohup.1.html) or [`screen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/screen.1.html). I have no idea why the session disconnects. For example, if you are using PuTTY you must set a non-zero value for the time between keepalives in the Connection options.

Comment: Why though? Is there a simple explaination why the process dies even though started as a background process with `&`? Isn't a background process detached from any SSH clients in that case?

Comment: It receives a SIGHUP signal (HUP = Hang-up, as in hanging up the phone). This has always been the rule, since the days when remote access was done using modems connected over telephone lines. `nohup` means `no hang-up`, it eats the signal and lets the background process live.

Comment: What receives the SIGHUP? also if I just `quit` the SSH connection, the java process still works. Isn't that strange? Shouldn't the java process die in that case?

Comment: The advantage of `screen` is that if the link is disconnected you will be able to reconnect to the session as it was.